# How can I run multiple db with same sql in python?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My goal is to be able to run both postgresql and mssql without changing the content of my sql query.

For example
"select top 1 * from ex.cust" this sql works in mssql. I want to run this in postgresql without replacing 'top' with 'limit'. So without doing that " select * from ex.cust limit 1".

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Yes write `select * from ex.cust limit 1` in both databases

Comment: Try using a SQLAlchemy Core query (`select()`) with `.limit()`. SQLAlchemy should emit the appropriate SQL statement for the current dialect, e.g., postgresql or mssql.